# Disable pay with credit card

Tags: paypal

I've got Buy Now Button:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="9HPJM3Z83ZCRS">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

But i dont want to let users pay with credit card, becouse i need to check their paypal email to prevent buying same thing twice. Is is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your PayPal account profile there is an option "PayPal Account Optional" that you need to disable in order to force all buyers to use a PayPal account.

Depending on the version of PayPal you're on, it will be in Payment Receiving Preferences, Website Payment Preferences, or something like that.  Just look around in your profile settings and you should be able to find it pretty easily.